# Gibt es eine genormte Aussprache für Standard-Deutsch?

Tags: pronunciation, standard-german

In letzter Zeit erschienen hier mehrere Fragen, die erkennen ließen, dass die Fragesteller von einer bestimmten Annahme ausgingen. Sie gingen davon aus, dass es für jedes Wort der deutschen Sprache genau eine einzige richtige Aussprache gibt, die im gesamten deutschen Sprachraum gültig ist. Die Annahme lautet:

> Wer fehlerfreies Hochdeutsch spricht, spricht das Wort »Wiese« auf eine ganz bestimmte Weise aus. Jemand, der dieses Wort anders ausspricht, spricht kein fehlerfreies Hochdeutsch. – Das Wort »Wiese« kann dabei durch jedes beliebige andere deutsche Wort ersetzt werden.

Ist diese Annahme richtig?

Falls sie falsch ist: Besteht ein Zusammenhang zwischen den Standardvarietäten der deutschen Sprache und der Aussprache?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Wer meine Antwort zu lang findet, darf gerne zum Abschnitt »Zusammenfassung« hinunterscrollen.

---

### Plurizentrische Sprachen

Es gibt derzeit ungefähr 5000 verschiedene lebende Sprachen. Davon haben etwas mehr als 30 Sprachen einen ganz besonderen Status. Sie sind plurizentrisch. Das heißt, dass es mindestens zwei geografische Gebiete gibt, in denen die dort lebenden Sprecher die Sprache auf unterscheidbare Weise beeinflussen. Es entstehen dann Varietäten dieser Sprachen.

Die Varietäten einer Sprache sind einander so ähnlich, dass es nicht gerechtfertigt ist sie als unterschiedliche Sprachen anzusehen.

Varietäten sind aber auch keine Dialekte. Für die verschiedenen Varietäten gibt es verschiedene Sätze von verbindlichen Grammatik- und Rechtschreibregeln. Für Dialekte gibt es keine Rechtschreibregeln, und die Grammatik eines Dialekts kann von der Grammatik der zugrundeliegenden Hochsprache manchmal weiter abweichen als die Grammatiken zweier Hochsprachen.

---

### Beispiele für Plurizentrik in anderen Sprachen

**Englisch**
Dass das Wort für »Farbe« in Großbritannien ("colour") anders geschrieben wird als in den USA ("color") wird als Teil des Grundwissens über die englische Sprache angesehen und wird auch an Schulen weltweit so unterrichtet.

Wenn man den Reden von David Cameron und Barack Obama zuhört, wird man deutliche Unterschiede in der Aussprache derselben Wörter wahrnehmen, und trotzdem wird niemand auf die Idee kommen zu behaupten einer von beiden spräche einen Dialekt. Beide Politiker sprechen in perfekter Weise jenes Englisch, das in dem Land das sie jeweils regieren Standard ist. Denn die beiden Staaten verwenden zwei unterschiedliche Varietäten derselben Sprache.

Britisches Englisch und Amerikanisches Englisch nehmen ganz selbstverständlich Seite an Seite gleichrangige Plätze ein. Indisches Englisch, Australisches Englisch und einige weitere englische Varietäten sind in der Wahrnehmung von Laien vielleicht nicht so präsent, stehen aber neben den beiden prominenten Varietäten ebenbürtig auf derselben Stufe.

**Spanisch**
Dass das Spanisch eines Kubaners anders klingt als das Spanisch eines Argentiniers, und beide wiederum ganz anders als die Muttersprache eines gebürtigen Spaniers, hört man auch wenn man die Sprache gar nicht beherrscht. Spanisch gibt es in mehreren Varietäten, und wer Spanisch als Fremdsprache lernt, wird im Unterricht auf diese Unterschiede hingewiesen.

**Portugiesisch**
In Brasilien gibt es seit den 1930er-Jahren Bestrebungen das Brasilianische Portugiesisch als eigenständige Sprache (mit dem Namen »Brasilianisch«) neben dem Portugiesischen Portugiesisch zu definieren, um sich noch stärker von der ehemaligen Kolonialmacht abzugrenzen.

**Arabisch**
In mehr als 1000 Jahren hat sich eine Vielzahl von regionalen arabischen Dialekten entwickelt, die so unterschiedlich sind, dass sich in vielen Fällen die Sprecher zweier verschiedener arabischer Dialekte nicht miteinander verständigen können. In den arabischen und nordafrikanischen Nationalstaaten wurden die jeweiligen ortsansässigen Dialekte zu Amtssprachen vereinheitlicht, wobei als gemeinsame Grundlage die Sprache des Koran großen Einfluss hatte. So entstanden die heute deutlich unterschiedlichen Varietäten der arabischen Sprache.

**tote Sprachen**
Varietäten gibt es auch in toten Sprachen. Dieselbe lateinische Bibelstelle wird in einem Musikstück beim Singen anders ausgesprochen wenn sie von einem italienischen oder von einem deutschsprachigen Komponisten vertont wurde. Und auch das nur noch in der Liturgie verwendete Kirchenslawisch liegt in fünf verschiedenen Varietäten vor.

---

### Deutsch als plurizentrische Sprache

Wie die obigen Beispiele zeigen, ist Plurizentrik bei Sprachen mit vielen Sprechern eher der Normalfall als die Ausnahme. So darf es nicht verwundern, dass auch Deutsch mit seinen knapp 100 Millionen Muttersprachlern eine plurizentrische Sprache ist.

Zu keiner Zeit in der Vergangenheit und auch nicht in der Gegenwart gab und gibt es ein einheitliches Deutsch, das im gesamten deutschen Sprachraum auf dieselbe Weise geschrieben und gesprochen wurde bzw. wird. Die Frage, ob jedes deutsche Wort überall im deutschen Sprachraum gleich ausgesprochen wird, ist daher mit einem klaren und deutlichen **NEIN** zu beantworten.

Warum das so ist zeigt Blick in die Vergangenheit:

**historische Entwicklung**
Die deutsche Sprache hat sich im Zentraleuropa des Frühmittelalters als Folge der zweiten Lautverschiebung als ein weit gefächertes Dialekt-Kontinuum aus den kontinentalwestgermanischen Dialekten entwickelt. Die Alamannen, Bajuwaren, Franken, Friesen, Sachsen und Thüringer hatten miteinander verwandte Stammessprachen, zwischen denen aber zum Teil erhebliche Unterschiede bestanden haben dürften.

Der deutsche Sprachraum war durch das ganze Mittelalter hindurch, bis hinein in die Neuzeit, sehr stark in viele kleine politische Strukturen zersplittert, was eine geografische Durchmischung der Bevölkerung erschwerte und so damit beitrug, dass sich die lokalen Dialekte relativ unabhängig von den Dialekten der Nachbarregionen entwickeln konnten.

Um das Jahr 1200 unternahmen deutschsprachige Dichter den Versuch ihre Werke in einer Sprache zu verfassen, die über die Grenzen eines lokalen Dialekts hinaus verstanden werden konnte. Dieses so entstandene Mittelhochdeutsch war eine künstlich geschaffene Ausgleichssprache, die zwar von so gut wie allen deutschsprachigen Menschen verstanden, aber von niemandem aktiv gesprochen wurde.

Außerdem hatte diese Dichter-Sprache kaum einen Einfluss auf die Sprache des Alltags, weil nur wenige Menschen lesen konnten, und weil es außer der händischen Abschrift noch keine Möglichkeiten gab die Texte zu vervielfältigen.

Im 14. Jahrhundert wurde abermals versucht die deutschen Dialekte unter ein gemeinsames Dach zu bringen, woraus das Frühneuhochdeutsch entstand. Das ist ebenfalls eine Ausgleichssprache, die von niemandem als Muttersprache gesprochen wurde, aber im deutschen Sprachraum gut verständlich war.

Vor allen Matin Luthers Übersetzung der Bibel in diese künstlich geschaffene Sprache und ihre weite Verbreitung durch den Buchdruck waren ganz wichtige Schritte auf dem Weg zu einem vereinheitlichten Deutsch.

Ein weiterer Meilenstein war die Schaffung einer einheitlichen Rechtschreibung durch das Wörterbuch der Gebrüder Grimm. Konrad Duden veröffentlichte 1880 ebenfalls ein deutsches Wörterbuch, das 1901 zum amtlichen Wörterbuch des deutschen Reiches erhoben wurde und bis 1996 das amtliche Wörterbuch Deutschlands blieb. Trotzdem gab es daneben auch innerhalb des deutschen Reiches noch andere Wörterbücher, die in Verwendung waren, z.B. das »Amtliche Wörterverzeichnis für die deutsche Rechtschreibung zum Gebrauch in preußischen Kanzleien« aus dem Jahr 1903.

Außerhalb des deutschen Reiches bzw. Deutschlands war der Duden zum einen nicht verbindlich, und zum anderen gab er eine Sprache wieder, die in Österreich und der Schweiz nicht verwendet wurde. Daher etablierten sich dort andere Normwerke der deutschen Sprache. In Österreich beispielsweise die »Regeln für die deutsche Rechtschreibung nebst Wörterverzeichnis – Ausgabe mit einheitlichen Schreibweisen in Österreich« aus dem Jahr 1904 und ab 1951 das amtliche Regelwerk »Österreichisches Wörterbuch«, das bis heute in der jeweils aktuellsten Auflage in Österreich verbindlich ist.

Besonders die letztgenannten Beispiele zeigen, dass der Versuch die deutsche Sprache zu vereinheitlichen, stark von politischen Grenzen beeinflusst wird. Auf diese Weise entstanden in den Staaten Schweiz, Österreich und Deutschland drei voneinander abweichende Ergebnisse beim Versuch aus regionalen Dialekten eine einheitliche Sprache zu erschaffen, die mit den drei Standardvarietäten der deutschen Sprache identisch sind.

Liechtenstein schloss sich sprachlich der Schweiz an, in Südtirol (in Norditalien) ist österreichisches Deutsch die an Schulen unterrichtete und in Ämtern verwendete Varietät, und in Belgien und Luxemburg sprechen und schreiben die deutschsprachigen Minderheiten deutsches Deutsch.

---

### Abweichung zwischen Schriftsprache und gesprochener Sprache

Die Tatsache, dass Hochdeutsch als Dachsprache geschaffen wurde um eine Vielzahl unterschiedlicher Dialekte zu vereinen, macht auch klar, warum das, was in den amtlichen und pseudo-amtlichen Regelwerken niedergeschrieben ist, kaum irgendwo mit jener Sprache übereinstimmt, die daheim im Wohnzimmer, im Pausenraum einer Schule oder abends in der Kneipe gesprochen wird.

Tatsächlich ist es nämlich so, dass die Mehrheit der Menschen mit Deutsch als Muttersprache zweisprachig ist ohne sich dessen bewusst zu sein. Sie sprechen im Alltag eine andere Sprache als jene mit der sie schriftlich kommunizieren. Besonders auffällig ist das in der Schweiz.

**Schweizerisches (Hoch-)Deutsch und Schweizer Deutsch**
Schweizerisches Deutsch ist eine der drei deutschen Standardvarietäten, aber sie existiert nur als reine Schriftsprache. Sogar im Schweizer Fernsehen ist diese Hochsprache nur selten zu hören. In der Schweiz spricht man Schweizer Deutsch. Das ist eine Gruppe alemannischer Dialekte für die es keine genormte Rechtschreibung gibt, weil niemand (von Mundartautoren abgesehen) diese Sprache zum Schreiben benutzt.

Die Schweizer Zeitungen werden aber in Schweizerischem Deutsch gedruckt. Diese Sprache wurde eigentlich im Zuge der Vereinheitlichung der deutschen Sprache aus Deutschland und seinen Vorgängerstaaten importiert und ist daher dem deutschem Deutsch sehr ähnlich. Die auffallendste Abweichung: Das Schweizerische Deutsch kennt kein »ß«. Aber niemand benutzt diese Sprache zum Sprechen. Sogar Politiker und die meisten Nachrichtensprecher sprechen stattdessen Schweizer Deutsch.

---

### Geografische Aussprache-Grenzen und Landesgrenzen

Die geografischen Grenzen der drei deutschen Standardvarietäten entsprechen genau den Grenzen der Nationalstaaten wenn man von Gebieten wie Südtirol und Luxemburg absieht. Jedoch sind diese drei Varietäten Ausprägungen der Schriftsprache, nicht der gesprochenen Sprache. Die Grammatik- und Rechtschreibregeln dieser Varietäten legen die Aussprache der Wörter nicht fest, sondern lassen sie völlig offen.

Wer etwas aus einem Buch oder einer Zeitung vorliest, muss selbst entscheiden wie welches Wort ausgesprochen wird, und dabei greift jeder Vorleser auf seinen eigenen Erfahrungsschatz zurück und damit auch auf die Laute die in dem lokalem Dialekt vorrätig sind, den der Sprecher spricht.

Wenn ein Sprecher einen Dialekt spricht, in dem kein stimmhaftes s existiert, wie das bei den oberdeutschen Dialekten der Fall ist (südlich der ungefähren Linie Straßburg-Stuttgart-Nürnberg-Plauen), dann wird er auch dann, wenn er »nach der Schrift« spricht, kein stimmhaftes s verwenden. In diesem Gebiet liegen aber jeweils vollständig die Staaten Schweiz und Österreich, so dass es in der Aussprache von Schweizerischem und Österreichischem Deutsch kein stimmhaftes s gibt.

Dieses völlige Fehlen eines stimmhaften s in Österreich und in der Schweiz ist aber *KEINE* Eigenschaft der jeweiligen Standardvarietät, sondern eine Folge der dort gesprochenen Dialekte.

Das stimmhafte s wird nämlich auch im Süden Deutschlands durch die stimmlose Variante ersetzt. Die »Wiese« wird von professionellen Nachrichtensprechern des Bayerischen Rundfunks ebenso wie von Sprechern des ORF mit einem stimmlosen s gesprochen, während deutschsprachige Sendeanstalten nördlich des »Weißwurst-Äquators« ein stimmhaftes s von ihren Sprechern verlangen.

Die Aussprache der gemeinsamen Dachsprache Deutsch wird also im gesamten deutschen Sprachraum sehr stark von der Aussprache der lokalen und regionalen Dialekte geprägt. Jedoch gibt es keine einzige Dialektgrenze, die mit einer Staatengrenze übereinstimmt.

---

### Zusammenfassung

1. Es muss zwischen der geschriebenen und der gesprochenen Sprache unterschieden werden.
2. Standardisiertes Hochdeutsch ist das Ergebnis des Versuchs eine gemeinsame Dachsprache für die Vielzahl von deutschen Dialekten zu finden.
3. Standardisiertes Hochdeutsch ist eine Schriftsprache, die meist nur bei offiziellen Anlässen (öffentlichen Reden) auch als gesprochene Sprache eingesetzt wird.
4. Die Standardisierung der deutschen (Schrift-)Sprache führte in der Schweiz, in Österreich und im deutschen Reich (später »Deutschland«) zu drei ähnlichen, aber dennoch unterschiedlichen Standards, die heute die drei Standardvarietäten der deutschen Sprache bilden.
5. Die Muttersprache fast aller Menschen mit Deutsch als Muttersprache ist nicht Hochdeutsch, sondern ein deutscher Dialekt.
6. Die Aussprache von Hochdeutsch ist nirgendwo genormt. In der Praxis folgt die Aussprache der Schriftsprache »Hochdeutsch« den Gepflogenheiten die für den jeweiligen lokalen Dialekt üblich sind. Insbesondere werden für die Aussprache von Hochdeutsch nur jene Laute (fachsprachlich: »Phone«) verwendet, die im Repertoire des jeweiligen Dialekts enthalten sind.
7. Die geografischen Grenzen zwischen unterschiedlichen Dialekten stimmen mit keiner einzigen Staatengrenze überein. Folglich lassen sich Variationen in der Aussprache *NICHT* an Staatengrenzen festmachen. Ebensowenig haben die drei Standardvarietäten einen Einfluss auf die Aussprache von Hochdeutsch.
8. Es ist nicht zulässig eine bestimmte der vielen Aussprache-Varietäten herauszugreifen und sie als die einzig richtige Art Deutsch zu sprechen gegenüber den anderen Aussprache-Varietäten hervorzuheben.

Comment: hmm... was soll das ganze Geseier? Bitte wesentlich kürzen und zum Punkt kommen! 90% hat kaum etwas mit der Frage zu tun...

Comment: @falkb Du verwechselst Ursache und Wirkung: Ich habe das Geseier nicht geschrieben um die von mir selbst gestellte Frage zu beantworten. Ich habe die Frage geschrieben um in derselben Sekunde das Geseier veröffentlichen zu können. Wenn ich also etwas ändern müsste, dann die Frage, nicht das Geseier. Da das Geseier aber schon ziemlich lang ist, wollte ich nicht auch noch eine elendslange Frage vorne dran flanschen.

Comment: Sehr lesenswert! Nur ein Kritikpunkt: Wenn du von Staatsgrenzen redest, meinst du dann nur heutige "richtige" Grenzen? In dem Fall verwundert deine Feststellung kaum, denn die Grenzen wurden ja in sprachhistorisch kurzer Zeit vielfach verändert (man denke an Südtirol). Somit würde ich das rauslassen. Ich denke nämlich, daß Grenzen durchaus auch Sprache beeinflussen können. Ich sage das als Exil-Thüringer, der inzwischen im ehemaligen Grenzgebiet  Württemberg/Hohenzollern/Sigmaringen lebt und mit der  Aussprache je nach ehemaligem Herrschaftsgebiet unterschiedlich schlecht zurechtkommt. :)

Comment: @Ingo, ja ich meine die Grenzen, die nach Ende des 1. Weltkrieges festgelegt wurden. Das sind nämlich, wie im Abschnitt »Geografische Aussprache-Grenzen und Landesgrenzen« erläutert, genau die Grenzen der Standardvariationen der Schriftsprache.

Comment: Was bedeutet "Geseier" ?

Comment: @GeorgesElencwajg: "Geseier" ist ein Schimpfwort. Es ist ein sehr unhöflicher, unfreundlicher und abwertender Begriff für überflüssiges Gerede. Siehe: http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geseier

Comment: Danke für die Erklärung, Hubert. Dass das Wort aus dem Jiddischen stammt hätte ich nicht erraten. Nebenbei gesagt: es sollten vielleicht solche Schimpfwörter in Kommentaren vermieden werden.

Comment: Na, das mit dem Schimpfwort ist ja jetzt total übertrieben. In meiner Gegend ist es ein umgangssprachliches harmloses Wort für "leeres Gerede". Man sollte einfach nicht versuchen auf wissenschaftlich zu machen, wenn man nicht vom Fach ist. Aber sorry wenn's als Schimpfwort rüberkam!

Answer (score 13):

Zwar gibt es keine verbindliche einheitliche Ausspracheregelung für die deutsche Sprache, dennoch gab es und gibt es Versuche einer Normierungen:

#### [Bühnensprache nach Siebs](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%BChnendeutsch)

Völlig auf die Bedürfnisse einer Theaterbühne ausgerichtet, wurde versucht, die Aussprache der Schauspieler auf den deutschen Theaterbühnen Anfang des 20. Jahrhunderts zu normieren. Diese Aussprache versuchte, Eigenheiten der verschiedenen Dialekte zu vereinen und fand breite Zustimmung. Schauspieler wurden und werden z. T. auch heute noch im Sprechunterricht zu dieser eigenen Aussprachevarietät erzogen.

#### [Aussprache der Nachrichtensprecher](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthoepie)

Mit zunehmender Verbreitung elektronischer Medien wie Radio und Fernsehen orientiert sich die heutige Aussprache zunehmend an den dort geltenden Regeln. Um hier eine Vereinheitlichung zu ermöglichen, und um die Nachrichtensprecher in dieser Sprache auszubilden, wurde die [Aussprachedatenbank der ARD](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/ARD-Aussprachedatenbank) ins Leben gerufen. Es handelt sich um eine Sammlung von häufigen oder auch neuen Wörtern, für die entsprechende Aussprachebeispiele hinterlegt sind. Im [Duden](http://www.duden.de) wird beispielsweise zu diesen Aussprachedateien verlinkt. Besonders bei der Aussprache neuer Wörter und Eigennamen sind diese Daten sehr hilfreich.

Diese Datenbank wird nicht nur von Sprechern in Deutschland benutzt:

> heute arbeiten alle Landesrundfunkanstalten, Deutschlandfunk - Deutschlandradio Kultur und Deutsche Welle sowie diese weiteren öffentlich-rechtlichen Rundfunkveranstalter mit deutschsprachigen Angeboten online mit der Datenbank: ARTE, ORF, SRF, Radio e Televisiun Rumantscha (rtr) im schweizerischen Chur und RAI Sender Bozen.<sup>[Aussprachedatenbank der ARD](http://www.ard.de/home/intern/fakten/abc-der-ard/ARD_Aussprachedatenbank____AusspracheDatenBank__ADB__der_ARD/563650/index.html)</sup>

Somit hat man trotz aller Unterschiede in der Aussprache der verschiedenen Regionen des deutschsprachigen Raumes eine gewisse Normierung an der Hand, die offenbar auch über die Landesgrenzen gültig ist, und auch in Österreich, der Schweiz und weiteren Regionen Anwendung findet.

Diese Vorgaben sind aber nicht verbindlich. Man wird anhand der Besonderheiten ihrer Aussprache weiterhin Sprecher finden, bei denen man eindeutig ihre sprachlichen Wurzeln hören kann. Das ist gut so und wird hoffentlich auch so bleiben.

#### Was soll man denn nun lernen?

Für das Erlernen der Sprache ist es hilfreich, wenn man sich an nur einer Aussprachevarietät orientiert. Eine Mischung verschiedener Aussprachevarietäten ist nicht nur verwirrend für Lernende, sondern wird auch von niemand als authentisch empfunden.

Wenn man sich die Unterschiede in der Aussprache des Standarddeutsch (nicht Dialekt!) zwischen Deutschland, Österreich und Schweiz in der ["Österreichischen Aussprachedatenbank (adaba)"](http://www.aussprache.at/), einem Projekt der Universität Graz, anhört, wird man feststellen, dass die Unterschiede so subtil sind, dass sie womöglich nicht einmal von Muttersprachlern eindeutig gehört werden können.

Comment: Dass der ORF (und andere Sendeanstalten) Zugang zur Ausprachedatenbank des ARD hat bedeutet nicht, dass sich die Sprecher des ORF daran orientieren. Tatsächlich gibt es eine eigenständige Aussprachedatenbank der Forschungsstelle für Österreichisches Deutsch, und dort findet man nicht nur die in Österreich gültige Aussprache, sondern auch die bundesdeutsche und die schweizerische. Diese Datenbank ist frei zugänglich: http://www.aussprache.at

Comment: Nun ja, die adaba ist eine gute Idee, aber es fehlen viele Wörter und meist kann mein (ungeübtes?) Ohr keinen Unterschied in der Aussprache bemerken, auch wenn ich einen erwarten würde (z.B.  *beispielsweise*, *Wiese*, *Kasten*, *Wurst*).

Comment: Insbesondere unterscheidet sich abgesehen von dem r-Laut in *Wurst* bei keinem der Beispiele die Lautschrift. Es wird nur im Österreichischen aus irgendeinem Grund *s̬* statt *z* verwendet. Außerdem kommen mir einige der Beispiele, insbesondere bei *beispielsweise,* computergeneriert vor.

Comment: "Aus irgendeinem Grund" ist im süddeutschen Sprachraum eben das stimmlose "s" deutlich weiter verbreitet. Was nur noch einmal die Annahme, es gebe eine "genormte Aussprache für Standard-Deutsch" widerlegt.

Für computergeneriert halte ich diese Beispiele jedenfalls nicht.

Comment: @Takkat Versuche es mal mit »Sekt« (achte auf das S), »Chemie« (ch), »Käse« (ä), »Schubkarre« (rr), »König« (g) oder Kaffee (welche Silbe wird betont?). Probiere dabei die weiblichen und männlichen Stimmen aus. Die männliche österreichische Stimme habe ich übrigens erkannt. Es ist die Stimme des leider schon verstorbenen ehemaligen Chefsprechers des ORF, Peter Fichna. Auch die weibliche österreichische Stimme kenne ich aus dem ORF, mir fällt aber ihr Name nicht ein. Übrigens höre ich bei »beispielsweise« vor allem bei den männlichen Stimmen einen deutlichen Unterschied beim letzten s.

Comment: @Ingmar: Wo ist da der Zusammenhang? Die zitierten Beispiele unterscheiden sich eben nicht bezüglich der Stimmhaftig- oder -losigkeit des *s. (Sekt* übrigens schon.)

Comment: (Fortsetzung) Und bei »Wurst« fällt mir auf, dass das r bei den deutschen Sprechern kehliger klingt als bei den Österreichischen. Bei »Kasten« höre ich keinen Unterschied, das deckt sich aber mit meinen Erwartungen. Und der Unterschied beim s in »Wiese« ist ebenfalls deutlich hörbar (stimmlos in Ö, stimmhaft in D).