# Darf man "Quadrat" als [kvatˈʁaːt] aussprechen?

Tags: pronunciation

Greift die Regel der Auslautverhärtung auch bei der Silbentrenung "Quad-rat"? Wenn es so ist, darf und soll man doch [kvatˈʁaːt] aussprechen, stimmt es?

Comment: you should listen to a German speak Portuguese, there are no "B's or D's" only "P's and T's", so I'd say YES

Comment: @Vickel: That depends on dialect. Saxons for example avoid K, P and T at any cost.

Comment: Man kann über das Härte-Niveau insgesamt diskutieren, aber das *t* am Wortende ist sicher härter als das am Ende der ersten Silbe. Und das Silbenende an sich ist auch nicht wirklich klar, siehe [DWDS](https://www.dwds.de/wb/Quadrat).

Answer (score 8):

Das *d* in *Quadrat* ist ein Silbenknie. Es gehört nicht eindeutig zu einer der beiden Silben, sondern bildet genau die Grenze zwischen den beiden Silben. Daher ist es auch nicht der Endlaut der ersten Silbe, daher auch kein Auslaut, und daher wird es auch nicht verhärtet.

Die korrekte Aussprache ist daher:

> [kvaˈdʁaːt]

Ähnliche Wörter sind:

- niedrig
- widrig
- Schwadron
- Quadriga
- Madrigal
- schludrig

Comment: *"Das d in Quadrat ist ein Silbenknie. Es gehört nicht eindeutig zu einer der beiden Silben, sondern ..."* Woher nimmst du nur immer solchen ... äh ... Unfug? Und selbst wenn stimmen würde, was du da ventilierst, wie kommst du dann zu der Behauptung, das *d* sei deshalb **nicht** usw. Das funktioniert qua Logik nicht. Aber es steht dir natürlich frei zu beweisen, dass *Quadrat* aus 3 Morphemen besteht, schon seit der Antike ... :-))

Answer (score 2):

Die Silbengrenze liegt vor dem *d*, so daß dieses nicht der Auslautverhärtung unterliegt: *Qua.drat*. Ähnlich vielleicht *be.drohen*.

Answer (score 1):

Ich kenne die Regel nicht, aber das "d" in "Quadrat" spricht man definitiv als weiches d.
Joahcim

Answer (score 0):

Im Deutschen gibt es [keine festen Regeln zur Aussprache](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/11538/gibt-es-eine-genormte-aussprache-f%C3%BCr-standard-deutsch). Es gibt allerdings Ausspracheempfehlungen. Danach wird das `d` in *Quadrat* weich gesprochen. Man darf aber schon auch hart sprechen und wird auch in der Regel verstanden.

Dort, wo ich wohne (Schwabenländle um Stuttgart), wird vieles weicher gesprochen, was aber manchmal dazu führt, dass Schwaben, wenn sie Hochdeutsch reden müssen, eine Verhärtung einführen, wo sie eigentlich gar nicht ist (`[kvatˈʁaːt]`). Das darf man bei uns so machen, es [ist nicht verboten](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/23068/war-die-deutsche-b%C3%BChnenaussprache-jemals-gesetzlich-vorgeschrieben), mag aber für einen Hinzugewanderten seltsam klingen.